# Profiling CPU, memory, networking performance and generating reports

Tags: cpu-usage, memory-usage, performance-monitoring, reporting, usage

## Background

I have a performance-intensive (i.e. consumes a lot of CPU cycles, memory, and network resources) application. Multiple instances of this application, along with some third-party vendor-specific services are running on my test system. I would like to profile, over a variable duration (i.e. a few minutes):

- The entire system (i.e. CPU/memory/network-interface usage).
- Individual applications (i.e. CPU/memory/network-interface usage for each running app).

I'd also like to generate usage-versus-time plots for the above profiling tests. For example:

[image]

---

## Work So Far

I originally intended to use the [CoreMark](https://www.eembc.org/coremark/) and/or [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) test suites for these tests, but it appears that both of these are **benchmarking/stress-testing** tools, not **system performance profiling** tools. If this is the case, [based on information from another Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/289942/tools-to-profile-memory-cpu-on-linux), I'd have to setup Nagios and use several different CLI tools plus scripts to get at the raw data I need (i.e. CPU/memory/netif usage by the whole system and by all running applications).

---

## Question(s)

1. Can [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) or [CoreMark](https://www.eembc.org/coremark/) generate CPU/memory/netif usage/statistics and pretty reports (i.e. system resources used versus time plots, summaries, etc.), **without stressing the system** (i.e. just profiling and reports, no stress-testing the system: I'm already doing that).
2. If (1) is a dead end, are there other FOSS/open-source reporting tools that can profile a system and applications?
3. Are there any projects that pull together multiple tools like Orca, munin, Nagios, etc.; to profile systems, or do most people "roll their own" profiling suite from scratch using these tools?

Thank you.